# Qt curllib not being able to add

Tags: c++, c++11, qt-creator, libcurl, qmake

Hi i am having a issue adding curl to my qt creator when i try and run a simple example of the curl website this one https://curl.haxx.se/libcurl/c/http-post.html i have added the libary using right the libary adding wizard i have also tried doing it manualy i still get this error: http://prntscr.com/rucmza
here is what the wizard has added to the .pro file

```
win32:CONFIG(release, debug|release): LIBS += -L$$PWD/lib/ -lcurl
else:win32:CONFIG(debug, debug|release): LIBS += -L$$PWD/lib/ -lcurld

INCLUDEPATH += $$PWD/include
DEPENDPATH += $$PWD/include
```

Comment: ok i have done this

Comment: I don't understand why you keep asking new questions when you don't bother to check or comment on the answers you've got to earlier ones.